# Calculation of $\pi_3^s$ via killing spaces and Steenrod squares

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

$\newcommand{\Sq}{\text{Sq}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Sf}{\mathbb{S}}$I am grateful to anyone who will help me, because I know it is not a short calculation and it requires some time. I hope that there is someone who enjoys, as me, these things.

I am (self) studying the book [Fomenko and Fuchs - Homotopical Topology](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-23488-5) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3497000)). In chapters 4 and 5 it discusses the Serre spectral sequence and cohomology operations and it shows how to compute $\pi_1^s, \pi_2^s$ using these tools. Then, in Lecture 31, it leaves $\pi_3^s$ as an exercise. Explicitly (p.417):

[image]

The $\Sf^n_{n+k}$ are the *killing spaces* of $\Sf^n$, i.e. the spaces with the same homotopy groups as $\Sf^n$ starting from $n+k$ and zero before. The $E_k$ are the *underkilling spaces* of $\Sf^n_{n+3}$, i.e. the spaces that at any stage quotient the $(n+3)$-homotopy group of $\Sf^n_{n+3}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ . We want to prove that this chain ends at $E_3$, i.e. that $H^{n+3}(E_3) \cong 0$, and conclude that $\pi_3^s \cong \Z_8$ (at $2$).

If I understood properly, I have to set up spectral sequences for six fibration:
\begin{align*}
K(\Z, n-1) &\to \Sf^n_{n+1} \to \Sf^n \\
K(\Z_2, n) &\to \Sf^n_{n+2} \to \Sf^n_{n+1} \\
K(\Z_2, n+1) &\to \Sf^n_{n+3} \to \Sf^n_{n+2} \\
K(\Z_2, n+2) &\to E_1 \to \Sf^n_{n+3} \\
K(\Z_2, n+2) &\to E_2 \to E_1 \\
K(\Z_2, n+2) &\to E_3 \to E_2
\end{align*}
Here is [the calculation I have done](https://docdro.id/tDUHwFm), but **it is not correct** because I obtain $H^{n+3}(E_3) \ncong 0$. Certainly it must be $\text{Sq}^1l_{n+3} \neq 0$, differently from what I wrote in the file.

I briefly explain the conventions in the pdf.

1. Coefficients ring is always $\Z_2$.
2. For every spectral sequences I show only three columns: the left column of the SS (cohomology of the fiber), the bottom row of the SS (cohomology of the base) (since we can choose $n$ so large to avoid terms in between) and the resulting cohomology of the total space. The differentials go up right by one position.
3. I marked in red the elements which do not survive in the SS.
4. I marked in blue the Steenrod-squares-relations which do not convince me: they do not convince me since I have the feeling that the Steenrod squares have the same problem of the cup product with spectral sequences, i.e. if they are 0 in $E_\infty$ maybe they are not really 0 in the total cohomology.

The point (4) is not discussed in the book, so probably I am not right and the error is somewhere else. If instead I am right, there would certainly be corrections that make things works (for example, if the last blue relation is wrong, then everything works). Anyway, it is an exercise from a book, so I suppose it must have a clear solution and the relations must not have the ambiguity that I am claiming.

EDIT I

I write here the four blue-marked relations

1. $\Sq^3 {i_{n+2}} = 0$. I think this is right, otherwise $\Sq^3 i_{n+2} = i_{n+5}' = \Sq^2 i_{n+3}'$. Then $i_{n+6}'' = \Sq^3 i_{n+3}' = \Sq^1\Sq^2 i_{n+3}' = \Sq^1\Sq^3 i_{n+2} = 0$, which is a contradiction.
2. $\Sq^4\Sq^1 i_{n+2} = i_{n+7}$. I think this is correct if 1) is correct. In fact $0 = \Sq^2\Sq^3 i_{n+2} = \Sq^4\Sq^1 i_{n+2} + \Sq^5 i_{n+2} = \Sq^4\Sq^1 i_{n+2} + i_{n+7}$.
3. $\Sq^1 k_{n+3} = 0$. This must be correct, otherwise the computation will end and we obtain that $\pi_3^s$ is $\Z_4$ at 2. By the way, **I cannot prove it**.
4. $\Sq^1 l_{n+3} = 0$. This must be wrong, but **I don't know how to prove it**.

(For the Adem relations I used [Alex Kruckman's Adem relations code](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekruckman/adem/).)

EDIT II

Since nobody answers, I make the question a little more general. I don't know how to solve 3, but I can imagine it's the same as 1: suppose that it is non-zero in order to get a contradiction using Adem's relations. I worry about 4 instead, because there I have to prove that *it is not zero*. Then my general question could be

> **If $\Sq^1x = 0$ in $E_\infty$ which are the common arguments that can I try to prove that $\Sq^1x \neq 0$ in the target of the spectral sequence?**

Comment: I have edited with a link to the book I think you mean and specific page and lecture references, but please correct if I got it wrong.  Also, when you define your commands, make sure that there is no whitespace after the closing `$`; that whitespace will appear in the rendered result, making it start with spurious blank lines or such.

Comment: I suggest you look at Mosher-Tangora as well as McCleary’s book on spectral sequences. They both have computations similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: @user51223 M-T seems to use different fibrations, but I will look. Anyway, if you know these computations and have some hints, I will be happy to hear them!